# Speaker set-up for a projector

Tags: speakers, setup, projectors

I am reconsidering buying external screen monitors to expand from my laptop and thinking more about buying a screen projector instead. What would be the best way to set up a speaker system from a projector viewpoint? I will be using this as both my personal/professional sound set-up. I like the space-saving aspect but want to make sure it won't have a negative effect on a sound system set-up. Any tips would be more than appreciated.

Have a great day and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with this kind of set up:

1. Projectors are not any higher resolution than your current monitor, most likely less.  Unless you've got the money for a 2k projector,  you'll just end up with really big icons and pixels.  You'll have to edit from across the room, so that does not save any room.
2. Projectors have fans to keep them cool.  This is a problem if you're trying to edit audio.  Unless you can house the projector outside of the room you edit in and have it shine through glass onto the screen, it will not be any better.

If you want a projector to watch movies on, go for it.  It's great, it's big.  But for data, it's not really worth the cost when you could get two nice data monitors for the same price or less.

As far as speakers, you'd do it the same as you would if you were using monitors.

Answer (score 3):

A speaker system from a projector viewpoint should be symmetrical relative to the listening position. Meaning where you will be sitting. There should a be Left and Right speaker 2ft minimum away from your screen and at tilted at 45 -60 degrees aiming at your ears, including the height and the capability of your room.

I assume you plan on getting a 5.1 system. Same left and right rules apply. The subwoofer speaker should be placed in between your left and right speaker aiming at you. Never against any object, another speaker or wall.

The center speaker in the center below your screen.

Left & Right Surround speakers should be placed accordingly to your listening/sitting position right above your head, to disperse the sound.

If you end up going 7.1 you will have to place your listening/sitting area 3-4 minimum away from a wall and place you Left and Right Back Speakers at the same height of the surround speaker yet behind your head and aiming at your ears.

When placing your set up, bring a friend and sit them where you will be sitting as a reference or place your chair.

Comment: that is: "... listening are 3-4 FEET away from a wall"